# Keyboard issues with my Estonian keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

How do I type greater than and less than sign on my Dell latitude e7240 PC.... It has an Estonian keyboard layout and not all keyboard characters are accurate.
For example when I try pressing the question mark symbol it displays another thing. I've tried all the settings I know to change it. What can I do...
Will changing the keyboard completely work out??

Comment: If the characters are different that means a wrong keyboard layout was set, period. Make sure it's set correctly and everything will work as designed.

Comment: Does the On Screen Keyboard (`C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe`) show a different keyboard? Questions: (1) Which are your Windows version and its language? (2) Please add to your post a screenshot of the OSK windows and a photo of your keyboard. (3) What language do you have in *Settings > Time & language > Language & region* under "Preferred languages"?

Answer (score 1):

You can install multiple keyboard layouts in most operating systems, such as Linux and Windows -- you did *not* state OS in the question. One can easily switch amongst layouts with a keypress. For example, for the PC on which this is being written, <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> cycles through each layout.

- In [Ubuntu](https://www.howtogeek.com/17508/add-keyboard-input-language-to-ubuntu/), for example,

  - Press <kbd>System</kbd>, type *sett*, and select *Settings*.
  - Select *Keyboard* in *Settings*.
  - Select the **+** (Plus) symbol to add a new layout.
- In [Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-the-input-and-display-language-settings-in-windows-12a10cb4-8626-9b77-0ccb-5013e0c7c7a2),

  - Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *lang*, and select *Language settings.
  - Select *Keyboard* control panel.
  - Select the **+** (Plus) symbol to add a new layout.

  [image: Windows Add Language]